# uwsgi no python application found

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Hello I'm trying to dockerize my flask application and put it behind a nginx using uwsgi, I followed almost every similar case I found but none worked. in my docker the flask app run like a charm in development mode but it doesn't with uwsgi, can you help me understand why ?

here is my folder:

```
└── server
    ├── app.py
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── dockerutils
    │   ├── nginx.conf
    │   ├── nginx-selfsigned.crt
    │   ├── nginx-selfsigned.key
    │   └── start.sh
    ├── Models
    │   ├── database
    │   │   └── databasemodels.py
    │   ├── routes
    │   │   ├── Admin_route.py
    │   │   ├── ChangeCreditials_route.py
    │   │   ├── Home_route.py
    │   │   ├── Login_route.py
    │   │   ├── Logout_route.py
    │   │   └── Register_route.py
    │   └── schemas
    │       ├── Admin_schema.py
    │       ├── Home_schema.py
    │       ├── Login_schema.py
    │       └── Register_schema.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── static
    │   ├── favicon.ico
    │   └── style.css
    ├── templates
    │   ├── admin.html
    │   ├── home.html
    │   ├── login.html
    │   └── register.html
    └── uwsgi.ini
```

**uwsgi.ini:**

```ini
[uwsgi]
module = app:app

uid = www-data
gid = www-data

master = true
processes = 1

socket = /tmp/uwsgi.socket
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
logto = /var/log/healthapp.log

die-on-term = true
```

**app.py:**

```py
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask, url_for, send_from_directory, redirect
from flask_restful import Api
from apispec import APISpec
from apispec.ext.marshmallow import MarshmallowPlugin
from flask_apispec.extension import FlaskApiSpec
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_wtf import CSRFProtect

from Models.database.databasemodels import db as db

from Models.routes.Register_route import Register
from Models.routes.Login_route import Login
from Models.routes.Home_route import Home
from Models.routes.Logout_route import Logout
from Models.routes.Admin_route import Admin

# app.add_url_rule('/favicon.ico', redirect_to='./static/favicon.ico')

def create_app():
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path='.env')

    dbusername = os.getenv('POSTGRES_ENV_USER')
    dbpassword = os.getenv('POSTGRES_ENV_PASSWORD')
    dbname = os.getenv('POSTGRES_ENV_DATABASE')
    dbhost = "postgredb"

    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)

    app.config.update({
        'APISPEC_SPEC': APISpec(
            title='Health API',
            version='v1',
            plugins=[MarshmallowPlugin()],
            openapi_version='2.0.0',
            # info={
            #     'description': 'This is the API for the Health project',
            #     'x-logo': {
            #         'url': url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico')
            #     }
            # }
        ),
        'APISPEC_SWAGGER_URL': '/doc/',
        'APISPEC_SWAGGER_UI_URL': '/doc-ui/',
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'postgresql://' + dbusername + ':' + dbpassword + '@' + dbhost + '/' + dbname,
    })

    docs = FlaskApiSpec(app)

    app.secret_key = os.environ.get('FLASK_SECRET_KEY')
    csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
    print(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])

    # ajoute les ressources à l'api et les joint à la route
    api.add_resource(Register, '/register')
    api.add_resource(Login, '/')
    api.add_resource(Logout, '/logout')
    api.add_resource(Home, '/home')
    api.add_resource(Admin, '/admin')

    # ajoute les ressources à la doc
    docs.register(Register)
    docs.register(Login)
    docs.register(Logout)
    docs.register(Home)
    docs.register(Admin)

    register_extensions(app)
    return app


def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
    with app.app_context():
        redirect(url_for('login',_method='GET'))
```

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:latest
COPY . /srv/flaskapp
WORKDIR /srv/flaskapp

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get full-upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y
RUN apt-get install -y nginx python3-dev python3-pip build-essential libpq-dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src

COPY ./dockerutils/nginx.conf /etc/nginx
RUN mkdir /etc/ssl/healthapp

COPY ./dockerutils/nginx-selfsigned.crt /etc/ssl/healthapp.crt
COPY ./dockerutils/nginx-selfsigned.key /etc/ssl/healthapp.key

RUN chmod +x ./dockerutils/start.sh && mv ./dockerutils/start.sh ./
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

in the end I have this logs in uwsgi

```
compiled with version: 10.2.1 20210110 on 10 June 2023 13:27:43
os: Linux-5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2
nodename: aba6c6d829cf
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 12
current working directory: /srv/flaskapp
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.socket fd 3
Python version: 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)  [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55ca20bd1b00
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145808 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 84)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 85, cores: 1)
```